# Restore Windows 8 ISO created with recimg on VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, windows-8, vmware-fusion

I need to create an image from my Windows 8 so I can use this image on VMware Fusion on my MacBook.

I use the `recimg` command to create the image. Can I use the image as an ISO file when creating the virtual machine on the Mac?

```
recimg -CreateImage C:\windows_image
```

Comment: Its not clear what software provides you the `recimg` tool.

Comment: @Ramhound It's [Windows itself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt-harrington/archive/2012/04/01/create-a-windows-8-refresh-image-with-recimg-exe.aspx).